# Effect on query time by adding indexes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get a query time down. I am using codeigniter ... queries where the records in the table are 100 or less ... the query is taking 2 millisec. One query thats getting 1 record from the table and has 2 where statement is taking 35 msec ... the table has 5000 records ...

```
        $this->db -> where ('DealSiteId', $q1['DealSiteId'] );
        $this->db -> where ('DealUniqueId',$q1['DealUniqueId'] );

        $dup= $this-> db -> get ('deals');
        $dup1 = $dup -> result();


      if (count($dup1)!=0){

            $data['error']="Duplicate, This deal already exists. ";
            return $data;
        }
```

I add indexes on both fields in where clause ... index type BTREE. Any faster way to check duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

If you created a compound index containing both fields, your query could use a single index making it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add individual indices on both fields or one combined one?

Either way, you should test your query directly in mysql (or something like phpMyAdmin) and use `EXPLAIN` to see what is happening: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

In you specific case, you could perhaps add a `unique` index / constraint for the combination of `DealSiteId` and `DealUniqueId`. That would look something like (untested, just to give you an idea...):

```
ALTER TABLE `deals` ADD UNIQUE `some_name` ( `DealSiteId` , `DealUniqueId` );
```

Answer (score 0):

Any easy way to determine if your query is as efficient as possible is to use [MySQL `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). To do this within CodeIgniter, you can do the following:

```
$this->db->where('DealSiteId', $q1['DealSiteId'] );
$this->db->where('DealUniqueId',$q1['DealUniqueId'] );

$result = $this->db->get('deals');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Take that printed result and run it against a MySQL command: `EXPLAIN <your query>`, this will tell you information about that query which will be useful. i.e. If it's using indexes, how many rows it's scanning, if it's using sort, creating temporary tables, etc. From there you can optimize your query to get the best result.